# Add percentage based fee/tax to specific product types on checkout

Tags: commerce, rules

In Drupal 7 Commerce, I have two product types, a service product and a physical product. I would like a 6% fee added to all physical products only when the user gets to the cart review page. Ultimately it would be a custom line item like a sub-total or tax.

Currently I've been able to add another sales tax to produce this functionality, however the tax is being applied to all products, rather than calculating the 6% on only the physical products. I'm not sure if this can be done with Drupal Rules, or if I'd need to use hooks.

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of anyone else who is looking for an answer to this, here is how I solved adding tax to only specific product types, based on comment #1 here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1251444

### Add elements to the rule applying tax to the line item

- Entity has field: Parameter: Entity: [commerce-line-item], Field: commerce_product
- Data Comparison: Parameter: Data to compare: [commerce-line-item:commerce-product:type], Data value: YourProductType

Add OR/AND for more based on needs.

Hope this helps someone!

[image: tax rule only to specific product types]